# How to solve second order Linear Nonhomogeneous Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'' + y= (cost)^{3}$
we know that $(cost)^{3} = \frac{1}{4}(3cost + cos3t)$

homogeneous : $y = c_1cost + c_2sint$

How to find particular solution?

Comment: Have you tried  the variation of constants method?

Comment: You can assume a solution in the form of the right hand side of the form $At\sin{t}+Bt\cos{t}+ D\cos{3t}+E\sin{3t}$, the extra factor of t is because your right hand side has a piece that is in your homogeneous solution

Comment: Since the equation is linear, you can find the particular solution for $\frac{3}{4}\cos t$ separately from the particular solution for $\frac{1}{4}\cos 3t$ and just add them up. This usually allows the equations you're solving to not span multiple lines and mitigates some potential arithmetic errors by doing less work at once.

Answer (score 0):

Note that by linearity, you may guess particular solutions to
$$
y_1''+y_1=\frac34\cos t
$$
and 
$$
y_2''+y_2=\frac14\cos 3t
$$
and sum them together, imposing your conditions, to find your particular solution.

For the first we guess a solution of the form
$$
y_1(t)=t(a\cos t+b\sin t)
$$
where $t$ is to insure linear independence from the homogeneous solution.

For the first, guess 
$$
y_2(t)=c\cos 3t+d\sin 3t
$$
I leave the rest to you.